# Can long cables induce that much noise?

Tags: analog, noise, rtd

[**UPDATE** The problem is fixed and the results are in my answer below]

I have designed a board with, among other things, six [MAX31865](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX31865-775735.pdf)'s on it. From those six I use five of them. The device reads out the temperature of five domes and if the temperature is to low or to high it sends an alarm sms via a gsm module.

Here some knogledge about the device:

- I use five 2-wire NI1000 RTD elements (like PT1000 just not as accurate)
- The probes are connected via 2-wire connection and each of them have their own max31865
- Every probe is connected via extension cable of minimum 20 meters
- The Domes where the sensors are in can have up to 90% air humidity
- the farthest probe is 100 meters away from the device
- Every 5 seconds I read out a different probes. 4 seconds before I initiate the conversion VBias is turned on. After the conversion I shut down VBias.

**Now to the problem:**

Four of the sensors I can read out without a problem. But if I connect probe 5 which is the farthest away from the device among the other four probes the max31865 from probe 5 spits out a ***over/undervoltage*** ***fault*** (fault D2). But if i connect only probe 5, the max31865 gives back valid temperature data. The conversion also works if I connect a probe next to probe 5, which is directly connected to the board (without extension cable).
*The fault means that the voltage on any input pin of the max31865 is >VDD or <GND1*

I changed the timing of "VBias ON -> Conversion, VBias off -> VBias ON" and I tried to let VBias always on but it didn't work.

How can it be that this over/undervoltage fault only occurs constant when sensor 5 is connected? (without probe 5 the error sometimes occurs with another probe but not that much) **Is it possible that the extension cable of the sensor is inducing so much noise that it can cause any protected pin to have a negative voltage or have a voltage greater than vdd?**

Thanks in advance!

The schematic of the sensor:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a schematic?

Comment: have you measured the voltage or are you just relying on the error code?

Comment: Shielded cable?

Comment: I measured the voltage on the pins at RTD+ and RTD-. On Sensor 5 the voltage on both pins are higher than on the other Sensors. (RTD- 0.1V instead of 0.05V and RTD+ 0.48V instead of 0.44V)  If VBias is not applied the voltage on those pins are changing in the 100mV range. The other Sensors show 0V.

Comment: @Jeroen3 No the cables are unshielded. Two of them have a multi-core and the other three have a single core. The cable size of all of them is 1.5mm2 (AWG 16)

Comment: I would suspect the total capacitance of the cables; it *may* be interfering with the communications. The amount of cable hanging on the communication port is quite high.

Comment: @PeterSmith Would that not just make the processing of the ADC in the max31865 slower because it has to charge the total capacitance of the circuit? (only the RTD- and RTD+ are connected to the long cable)

Comment: @ruemi: it could play havoc with clock, cs and data edge rates (a common problem in communications). What speed are you trying to run that interface at?

Comment: @PeterSmith Thank you for the explanation. The SPI Interface runs at 400kHz. Would it change something if I would increase or decrease the current through the cable and the probe? The "funny" thing is that I can read the probe without a problem if it is connected alone. But as soon as I connect the others (not even measuring just connecting the other probes) it generates a error.

Comment: With respect to *Peter*, I interpret your problem differently. Your error flag in the MAX31865 (fault status bit D2) refers to the RTD i/f and not the SPI i/f. Also, the difference you describe with "sensor 5" is the length of the RTD cable, again nothing to do with SPI. Some diagrams would help, to see various cable lengths visually, inc the SPI cables (one per MAX31865?) in case my interpretation is wrong. In any case, you have "good" and "failing" configs and there are tests which may help you find the *relevant* differences between them, but some would need a 'scope. Have you got one?

Comment: @SamGibson The RTD Sensor is the only thing connected from the outside of the board. All the other connections are routed on the pcb. I do have a scope (and for the inspection of the spi I used a logic analyzer). What kind of diagrams and tests are you talking about?

Comment: @ruemi (a) That *seems* to confirm no SPI difference between sensor 5 & others. (b) I meant wiring diagrams showing length & type of the various cables (RTD, SPI, any others) any relevant physical / environmental objects e.g. locations of motors, arc welders, alien space ships etc. :-) which could influence RTD signals. (c) *Many* tests are possible (not enough room to list) - I would apply [Kepner-Tregoe](http://www.kepner-tregoe.com/) techniques looking for diffs between "good" & "bad" e.g. compare with 'scope: sensor 5 & 4 signals; sensor 5 "bad" & sensor 5 "good"; MAX31865 Vcc quality etc.

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks a lot for the answer! (a) that really seems to be the case because i can connect the probe 5 to an other measurement port and the fault is the same. (b) For the length i know that probe 5 has a cable lenght at about 150m. Another probe is connected at about 80m away from the device. The other three are between 20m and 50m. The cable of the probe 5 runs in parallel with different cables in a cable channel and at one spot it crosses a wireless router. I'll look into that and apply the tips from (c).

Comment: @SamGibson an appendix to (b): The cable to the probe 5 is a 1.5mm2 multi-core cable in a plastic jacket. One of the short probe cable is also a multi-core cable. The other 3 probe cables are single-core 1.5mm2 cables in a plastic jacket.

Comment: On all of those shielded cables, the shield is only grounded at one place, right?

Comment: @rdtsc - *"On all of those shielded cables, the shield is only grounded at one place, right?"* Hi - Did you mean to comment *here*? Because up to this point in the comments above, the details were that "[the cables are unshielded](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/317056/can-long-cables-induce-that-much-noise#comment738609_317056)". The introduction of shielded cables was after my suggestion, where I did recommend "shield grounded at one end (typically the "measuring end") only". Or do you have information I missed, that the original cables were shielded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to fully understand your RTD cabling, since you've mentioned "Two of them have a multi-core and the other three have a single core", yet you would need *at least* two wires to connect to each RTD, so using a single core (wire) seems impossible!

[**Update** - Above original wiring now clarified in later comment to have been: Two sensors using cables with *stranded* wires, and the other three sensors using cables with *solid core* wires.]

However, some of the other information suggests the answer to your original question *could be* "yes". Noise induced in the sensor 5 cable (from external sources) seems to fit with information presented so far, and being the longest cable, it's not a surprise that this sensor would be *more* affected than the other sensors, which have shorter cables.

> the cables are unshielded

Use of long unshielded cables for RTDs is a concern, especially if external sources of electrical noise are present. You've also explained that the affected sensor is the one with the longest cable (150m). That's an interesting correlation. Shielded, twisted conductor (2, 3 or 4 wires) is a common cable type for long RTD cables, with the shield grounded at one end (typically the "measuring end") only.

The use of only 2-wire connections to the RTDs, especially with long cables, will affect the accuracy of the measurements, although that might not be important to you.

> The cable of the probe 5 runs in parallel with different cables in a cable channel and at one spot it crosses a wireless router.

Again, it's an interesting correlation between that long cable run, *close* to other cables (potential "radiators") and the wireless router (a *definite* radiator) and the affected sensor. That is especially interesting if the cables to the other sensors, are further away from potential and actual EM radiators.

> On Sensor 5 the voltage on both pins are higher than on the other Sensors. (RTD- 0.1V instead of 0.05V and RTD+ 0.48V instead of 0.44V) If VBias is not applied the voltage on those pins are changing in the 100mV range. The other Sensors show 0V.

That is interesting. The difference between the sensor 5 measurements and those from other sensors, is telling you something. If you can do more work to understand the *specific* differences, and what changes them (i.e. what makes those differences increase or decrease), you can extract more value from that difference.

This is an example of the type of difference which can form part of the tests, comparing the measurements between "good" and "bad" configurations which I mentioned in earlier comments (if you are experienced with that type of troubleshooting approach - but you might prefer to follow a different approach of your own).

I assume those voltage measurements you listed were made with a DMM. I would use a 'scope and look at the voltages on those sensor 5 signals, and use that to try to find the cause e.g.:

- What is the waveform shape? Does the magnitude match what you measured with the DMM or is it different (perhaps larger)?
- Is there more AC ripple at 50Hz/60Hz (whatever the mains frequency is at the affected site) on the sensor 5 cables, compared to the cables from other sensors?
- Are the cables which are parallel to the sensor 5 cable, carrying mains power, or low voltage signals, or something else? Can you match that answer to whatever induced voltage waveform you see on the sensor 5 cable?
- Is the waveform shape and magnitude of the externally induced voltage on the sensor 5 cable, different from that on the cables to other sensors? Anything unusual, considering cable length and routing for each cable?
- Can you temporarily switch off the wireless router close to the cable for sensor 5, and see whether the faults reported by its MAX31865 stop or are reduced?

Also ensure that you have selected the correct "notch frequency" (50Hz or 60Hz  - whatever is the local mains frequency) in the configuration of the MAX31865, so that it has the best chance of ignoring induced voltage at that frequency.

> How can it be that this over/undervoltage fault only occurs constant when sensor 5 is connected? (without probe 5 the error sometimes occurs with another probe but not that much)
>   [...]
>   The "funny" thing is that I can read the probe without a problem if it is connected alone. But as soon as I connect the others (not even measuring just connecting the other probes) it generates a error.

I suggest you look for differences in *any* measurement, between the different cases. If nothing changes (between different test cases) to cause different voltages to be externally induced in the sensor wiring to *other* sensors, then the "better" behaviour when only sensor 5 is attached may suggest an additional problem.

One hypothesis which might start to explain that, could be that externally induced voltages from *all* sensors are fed back to the "controller" (i.e. MAX31865 devices) and have some sort of *cumulative* effect there. This could explain why connecting sensor 5 *on its own* is not enough to cause errors to be reported ("only" 150m of cable attached); whereas when *all* sensors are attached (e.g. 250-300m [my guess] of cable attached in total, spread over 5 channels) this has a worse effect on the MAX31865 devices, enough for errors to be reported. This is why I suggested (in a comment) looking at the Vcc supplies for the MAX31865 devices - that's just an initial place to start looking; look for any measureable differences at the "controller board", when different numbers of sensors are connected.

That data point of when *only* sensor 5 is attached you don't get errors, is telling you *something*, but I'm not sure exactly what it means with the data given so far. Either gathering additional data and finding anomalies, or performing substitution tests (e.g. changing the cable type) and getting different results, will help.

I wasn't joking when I suggested making a diagram of the physical layout of the sensor wiring and potential interference sources. That may help you to understand the timing of when the MAX31865 reports errors, e.g. if that correlates with the operation times of specific interference sources.

It seems possible that the only way to resolve these errors, may be to rewire with suitable shielded, twisted conductor cabling. Depending on your budget, time pressures, availability of suitable shielded cabling etc., one option is that you could choose to take a risk, postpone additional investigation at this stage, and perform some testing with equivalent lengths of that different cable, laid temporarily in the same position as the existing sensor 5 cable. Get some measurements with the 'scope and see if there is an improvement in the magnitude of the induced voltage and, of course, see if you still get errors from the MAX31865.

Inevitably that approach has risks e.g. it *might* be a waste of time/money, but it would allow you to gather useful measurements, to see if the shielded, twisted conductor cable helped at all.

One final thought: The hypothesis is that your system is suffering from externally induced voltages, especially on sensor 5. When that voltage is large enough, it triggers the fault detection in the MAX31865 to set bit D2 in the Fault Status Register. However perhaps that induced voltage would not *always* be large enough to trigger the fault detection, and instead it might only cause erroneous temperature readings. It would be interesting if you are seeing unexpected intermittent high or low readings (especially on sensor 5, but the other sensors too), as well as the actual faults reported by the MAX31865.

I hope that review of the information, suggestions for additional data gathering and hypotheses to consider, are helpful. However getting a *conclusive* answer to your question, will require more work.

Comment: For the used cables I meant that it is a cable with two wires in it, each with a size of 1.5mm2. Two of the extension cables have stranded wires the other three have solid wires in it. Thank you for all your help. It helped a lot!

Comment: @ruemi - I'm glad I could help :-) I've updated my answer to clarify the details about the wiring which you have given. I don't believe the difference between stranded & single-core wiring will affect the signals significantly, if that was the only difference between the cables.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to SamGibson I could narrow down the problem.
I tried to eliminate the possible radiation devices. It changed a bit but not enough. After quite a bit of measuring I decided to exchange the cable. We luckily had enough Cat.6 ethernet cable in house and I did some tests with the hole spool. The results were promising so we replaced the old cable. The results are very good (in comparison to the old cable).
Here are some results:

On the left is probe 5 without any other probe connected. On the right is probe 5 with the other probes connected. Both measured on RTD+:
[image]

On the left is a probe with a closer distance to the device with a unshielded cable. On the right is probe 5 with the shielded cable. Both with the other probes connected and measured on RTD+:
[image]

The result is that probe 5 with the shielded cable is as good as the sensor that is at about 80m with the unshielded cable. As it changed so much for this sensor I might also change the other cables.

> It would be interesting if you are seeing unexpected intermittent high or low readings (especially on sensor 5, but the other sensors too), as well as the actual faults reported by the MAX31865.

I do see a deviation on the temperature measurements up to 0.8°C. I guess if I change the other cables it would reduce the amount of noise significantly.  The fault of the max31865 disappeared nearly completely.